# Proving the Success of data mining models

Tags: data-mining

I am a bit confused on how can we verify the usefulness of our `data mining models` produced through `data mining algorithms`. For `classification`, I'm sure we can `Partition` data into testing and training sets. How do we identify the effectiveness of models produced from `clustering and association`?

Comment: You can define test sets for clustering and association as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Association rules can be used for prediction and thus can be evaluated the same way by splitting your data.

Clustering: how would you *use* the result anyway?

The way to "prove" clustering is to either use the result to improve classification performance, or by providing insights to a *human* user. If the user gained insight from clustering, then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For clustering (and association rules) you can verify the accuracy by using cross-validation. For instance, Weka provides tools to check clustering accuracy, so that you can tune in the parameters (e.g., the number of clusters etc.) Check this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103560/how-to-compute-accuracy-for-cluster-evaluation-in-weka)